# How to do a wrapped text finder?

Tags: c++, qt, find, qtextedit

I am working on a text finder in QtCreator(c++). I used a "QtextEdit::find" function and it finds every occurrence of the searched word until the document reaches the end, when a NEXT button is pushed. Now I want to add a "QCheckBox" that when checked restart the "finder" at the beginning of the document and continues the search.
Do you have any suggestions how to do that, considering that the "QTextEdit::find" returns a bool? 
Here is the my find function:

```
void textFinder(const QString& textToFind, bool rev, bool wrappedSearch)
{
 QTextDocument *document = this->document();
 QTextCursor cursor (document);

QTextDocument::FindFlags flag;
if (rev == flag)
  flag |= QTextDocument::FindBackward;

bool found = find(textToFind, flag);

if (wrappedSearch == true){
   cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
}

}
```

The tool bar that I did contains a `QLineEdit`, `QPushButton`, and a `QCheckBox`.

Comment: please attach your code and your tryings to achieve what you are asking about.

Comment: I not familiar with `c++` but from the concept of OOP, what if you listen to that checkbox and when it checked do  `cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);`

Comment: @OanaS. So what's the problem? I don't see why `QCheckBox` bothers. Could you be more specific?

Comment: The problem is that this code does not do the trick of starting the searching all over again, when the document reaches the end.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat The `if (wrappedSearch == true)` means it is cheked

Comment: well, may be I misunderstood your explanation, so, you are doing it but it's not working, not don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answears ! Those helped me a lot. For my code, it worked like this:

```
    if (searchWrapped == true && !found){
        if (rev == false && cursor.atStart() == true){
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
            found = find (text, flag);
        }

        if (rev && cursor.atEnd() == true){
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
            found = find (text, flag);
            }
        }
        setTextCursor(cursor);

}
```

Comment: Wait, if you're searching forwards and no results were found and the cursor is at the start, you move the cursor to the end? If you're searching forwards, surely you want to move the cursor back to the start if there were no results found? I'm not sure why you're checking for the cursor position anyway, the last search result isn't always going to be at the end/start of the document.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question you want help with implementing wrapped search. Then I think it will suffice to perform another search after having moved the cursor to either start or end of document depending on whether reversed search or not:

```
void textFinder(const QString& textToFind, bool rev, bool wrappedSearch)
{
    QTextDocument *document = this->document();
    QTextCursor cursor (document);

    QTextDocument::FindFlags flag;
    if (rev == flag)
      flag |= QTextDocument::FindBackward;

    bool found = find(textToFind, flag);

    if (!found&&wrappedSearch == true)
    {
       cursor.movePosition(rev?QTextCursor::End:QTextCursor::Start);
       found = find(textToFind, flag);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few problems with your code and the logic inside it.

First of all, I don't understand why you are comparing your `rev` bool to the `flag` variable. Shouldn't you compare it against `true`? I'd also set the initial value of the `flag` variable to `0`.

Second of all, if the wrapped search is set to true, you should only wrap it if `QTextEdit::find` returned `false`. Otherwise you'd be stuck at the beginning of the document.

Then you should also check if the value `rev` is `true` before setting the cursor to the beginning. If you are searching backwards, you should set the cursor to the end of the document when wrapping.

And you also have to set the text cursor back to your text edit after modifying it.

Here is my working search function, I didn't subclass `QTextEdit` because I was lazy, but the logic is the same.

```
void MainWindow::findText(const QString &text, bool rev, bool wrapped)
{
    QTextDocument::FindFlags flag = 0;
    if(rev)
      flag = flag | QTextDocument::FindBackward;

    bool found = ui->textEdit->find(text, flag);
    if(!found && wrapped)
    {    
        QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
        if(!rev)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
        else
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
        ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
        ui->textEdit->find(text, flag);
    }
}
```